# A doubt on the action of NBS/CCl4

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Suppose we have a alkene( ex- 2- butene)  we try to subject it to allylic bromination using NBS/CCl<sub>4</sub> and then the mixture is separated using fractional distillation. According to me as the reaction proceeds with a free radical pathway we must get  three  products namely cis , trans  1-bromobut-2-ene and the rearranged  product but the answer is given as that the fractions obtained will be only 2 . Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Is your but-2-ene starting material an E/Z mixture or single isomer?

Comment: Not specified and that is the main problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite correct that this is a radical bromination, know as the Wohl–Ziegler reaction. The mechanism is here [Wohl–Ziegler](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/wohl-ziegler-reaction.shtm). The key point is that the radical intermediate at the allylic position is stabilised by resonance with the double bond giving a 3-centred intermediate. This can brominate at either end (favouring the more substituted), but it does not isomerise the double bond. So I think the question setters are refering to 3-bromobut-1-ene and 1-bromobut-2-ene as the possible products without concerning themselves with the E/Z isomers.

Comment: The OP suggested (E)-"ex"-2-butene as a substrate (bp 0.8 oC). Given that the W-Z NBS reaction is normally done in refluxing CCl4 (bp 77 oC) to enhance the solubility of NBS. There may be difficulty in containing the substrate in the reaction vessel. Dry ice/actone condenser???

Comment: A poorly chosen example substrate, perhaps.